# Can't click on Button in popping up Overlay Container on Website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate my vaccination appointment search. Therefore I automated the filling-in of the Website by using selenium and chromedriver in Python. The first steps work fine, but I am stuck at a point where a separate window overlays the original form, after i filled in a checkbox. The popping up overlay is not an iframe, hence switching frames didn't work. Using find_element_by_xpath does not work: Neither for finding the button on the overlay, nor finding the general overlay at all. I also tried:

```
element = WebDriverWait(web,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-  dialog-13"]')))
element.click
```

In case the overlay just needs some time to be visible, but this leads to the `exceptions.TimeoutException:`

Can anyone help?
Here is the Webpage: https://www.impfportal-niedersachsen.de/portal/#/appointment/public

I am stuck at following point of the dialogue:
[Popping UP Overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifw47.png)

Hence I just need to accept the "Verstanden Button" in this window to continue my workflow....

Edit: Here is the HTML of the "Verstanden" Button:

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button="" tabindex="-1" color="primary" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary _mat-animation-noopable" style=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper">Verstanden</span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
```

The "Verstanden Button is on the bottom of the new window. I tried scrolling down to it, but therefore python must find where to scroll first. That's why I tried to click on the new window first, but that's where I am stuck.

When I first tried the workflow, I directly tried to "click" on the first Checkbox at the bottom of the page, as on the previous steps of the form:

[Checkbox to be set to "Ja"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu0eu.png)

But it seems that the popping window prevents python from finishing clicking into the checkbox, as I got the exception:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException:
```

Hence I added (I called my driver "web"):

```
try:
    #Tries to click on the Checkbox to be set to "Ja"
    web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-radio-9"]/label/span[1]/span[2]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    # if checkbox is hidden by new window, press Verstanden Button
    PopUpButton = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mat-dialog-14"]/confirm-dialog/mat-dialog-content/div/button')
    time.sleep(2)
    PopUpButton.click()
```

However, if executing the code like this, I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mat-dialog-14"]/confirm-dialog/mat-dialog-content/div/button"}
```

Here is the HTML of the whole block where I am stuck (I divided it):

```
<mat-dialog-container tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c33-39 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" id="mat-dialog-14" role="dialog" style="transform: none;">
```

```
<confirm-dialog class="ng-star-inserted" style="">
```

```
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-dialog-content" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
```

```
<h2>Bitte beachten Sie:</h2>
<p>Wir weisen Sie daraufhin, dass das Vorliegen einer <b>medizinischen oder sonstigen Impfberechtigung</b> mithilfe geeigneter Unterlagen im Impfzentrum nachgewiesen werden muss.<br><br>Ein geeigneter Nachweis ist beispielsweise<ul>    <li>         eine Bescheinigung der Ärztin oder des Arztes, welche die Berechtigung der nach der CoronaImpfV genannten Erkrankung bestätigt.    </li>    <li>         das durch die Krankenkasse übermittelte Schreiben der Frau Ministerin Behrens zur Berechtigung zur Schutzimpfung gegen das Covid-19-Virus.    </li>    <li>         eine formlose schriftliche Bestätigung durch die jeweilige Einrichtung.    </li>    <li>         eine schriftliche Bescheinigung (von der pflegebedürftigen bzw. schwangeren Person oder einer Vertretung ausgefüllt und unterschrieben), welche die Versicherung beinhaltet, dass nur bis zu zwei Personen benannt werden und die in der Bescheinigung benannte Person zu dem Kreis der Berechtigten gehört          (einen Vordruck finden Sie hier: <a target="_blank" href="https://www.niedersachsen.de/download/167141">https://www.niedersachsen.de/download/167141</a>),          <b>und zusätzlich</b> eine Bestätigung über die Pflegebedürftigkeit der zu pflegenden Person (z.B. Kopie des Nachweises über einen Pflegegrad oder ärztliche Bestätigung) oder bei schwangeren Personen eine Kopie aus dem Mutterpass mit dem Ausstellungsdatum und dem Namen der Schwangeren bzw. einen gleichwertigen Nachweis.    </li>    <li>         Für die <b>Härtefallregelung</b>: Erforderlich ist die Bescheinigung einer Ärztin oder eines Arztes oder einer psychologischen Psychotherapeutinnen oder eines Psychotherapeuten, die die impfwillige Person innerhalb der letzten 12 Monate wegen der die Priorisierung begründenden Erkrankung regelmäßig behandelt haben, dass nach ärztlicher Beurteilung der besonderen Umstände des Einzelfalls ein sehr hohes, hohes oder erhöhtes Risiko für einen schweren oder tödlichen Krankheitsverlauf nach einer Infektion mit dem Coronavirus SARS-CoV-2 besteht, sofern es sich um eine Erkrankung handelt, die nicht bereits in § 3 und § 4 der CoronaImpfV aufgeführt ist.    </li></ul>Wir bitten Sie, diese Unterlagen zu Ihrem Termin mitzubringen.</p><br>
```

```
<div fxlayout="row" fxlayoutgap="10px" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
```

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button="" tabindex="-1" color="primary" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-primary _mat-animation-noopable" style="">
```

```
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">Verstanden</span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
```

```
<!----></div></mat-dialog-content></confirm-dialog><!----></mat-dialog-container>
```

Comment: Where is _Verstanden Button_ button in that window ? If possible could you share HTML in text format here.

Comment: I get this error also `Access to the vaccination portal of the state of Lower Saxony is not permitted from your location.
Please use the possibility of making an appointment via the citizen hotline 0800 9988665.

HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Comment: Does accessing the site with fake gps work? I could also provide the whole HTML segment of the window where I am stuck.

Comment: Yes Please share HTML where you are stuck,  we can look into that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML as a code block. It is fine to post screenshots of the page, but code in screenshots is difficult to read.

Comment: Hope my edit is what you need, or should I post everything just into one block?